# Do you know a way to change the loop for something more productive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

i'm looking to do that loop with the condition in a way that is simpler and more productive. Can anybody can think of a way to do it? Thank you in advance for your help!! :)

```
OptVariableControle =np.array([])    
    j = 1
    for i in range (0,27):
        if  i == 2 :
            j = j+1
        if  i == 5:
            j = j+1
        if  i == 8:
            j = j+1
        if  i == 11:
            j = j+1
        if  i == 14:
            j = j+1
        if  i == 17:
            j = j+1
        if  i == 20:
            j = j+1
        if  i == 23:
            j = j+1
        OptVariableControle =np.append(OptVariableControle, 
                        (optionsActualise[i] + betas["beta" + str(j)]* (optionsActualise[i]-esperences[i])))
```

Hello, It would be almost impossible for me to put all my code here. But I can confirm that betas is a dictionary of 10 (1 to 10) elements,  optionsActualise and esperances  are  np.array of shape (27,).

Finaly made it work with that :

```
betas_arr1 = np.array([betas[f'beta{j}'] for j in range(0, 9)])
OptVariableControle =np.array([])    


OptVariableControle = optionsActualise + betas_arr1[np.arange(0, 27) // 3] * (optionsActualise - esperences)
```

I hope this is enough

Comment: It looks like we always have `j == 1 + (i+1)//3`.

Comment: Has the `i == 26` case been omitted intentionally?

Comment: Go back to using a list and list append.

Comment: You'll need to move away from Python datastructures entirely if you want to avoid a python level loop.

Comment: Please provide a complete runnable example with inputs we can test with.

Comment: @hpaulj. Not really necessary. There is only one python datastructure here, assuming the things that look like arrays are arrays, and it can be factored out completely.

Comment: While I appreciate you selecting my answer, could you please update your question to contain an MCVE, and fix the indentation? We don't even know the sizes and types of the objects you are referencing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a good reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First preprocess `betas` to be a numpy array of reasonable size. I'm assuming it is a dictionary or similar mapping:

```
betas_arr = np.array([betas[f'beta{j}'] for j in range(1, 10)])
```

Next, note that you increment `j` whenever `i + 1 % 3 == 0`. The array-ification of `betas` also changes the index `j` to start with 0. That means that for any given `i`, `j` is just `(i + 1) // 3`.

Assuming that `optionsActualise` and `esperances` are numpy arrays, you can compute `OptVariableControle` without a loop:

```
OptVariableControle = optionsActualise + betas[np.arange(1, 28) // 3] * (optionsActualise - esperences)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **modulus (%)** operator. As you are checking `i` with a number and if it's true you want to increment `j` by 1. There is a pattern here, the number you are checking gives **remainder of 2 when divided by 3**, here's how you can implement this *pattern* logic to make the checking simpler, productive and compact:

```
OptVariableControle =np.array([])    
    j = 1
    # Replaced 27 by 26 here, as you do not want j to change when i is 26
    for i in range (0,26):
        if  i %3 == 2 :
            j = j+1

        OptVariableControle =np.append(OptVariableControle, 
                        (optionsActualise[i] + betas["beta" + str(j)]* (optionsActualise[i]-esperences[i])))
```

Comment: I don't think you need a loop at all. Certainly `np.append` is a bad idea.

Comment: FutureJJ thanks for the comment and this is what I've tried at first but I can't get the last value of optionsActualise and esperences that way since optionsActualise.shape = (27,)